# How to change failure message for Alexa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to change the default failure message in Alexa, `Sorry, I'm having trouble accessing your {} skill right now`.

Comment: Do you own the skill ? What sdk are you using ?

Comment: Yes, I own the skill, nodeJs sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change that prompt but you can code to avoid that as much as possible.  The error happens when Alexa is not able to get a valid response from your skill endpoint. There can be multiple reasons to that as mentioned here

**1. Your endpoint is giving an invalid response**

This can be due to the errors/exceptions happening in your endpoint code. You can make sure that error/exceptions don't occur and if they occur, thre is code to catch them and provide a valid response back to Alexa, with an error message of your choice.

**2. Your endpoint availability**

Make sure that your endpoints are available all the time if you have configured them as an endpoint. This is pretty much guaranteed if you are using Lambda endpoints. But if you are your own hosted web service endpoint, then you must put in all the measures to keep it available for Alexa to communicate with it.

**3. Your endpoint response time**

Make sure that your endpoint gives back the response within the time period that Alexa expects it to get(guess its 10 seconds). Also make sure if you are using Lambda functions, you have configured them with reasonable execution time to avoid timeout errors.

If you cover the exception/error/availability scenarios well then you can avoid the default error message as much as possible.

Comment: By adding handler for SesionEndedRequest can we do it?

Comment: What would you do when the session has already ended. This handler is to clear resources on your service side when the session has ended.

Comment: `https://www.jovo.tech/docs/routing/intents#end` I read about that here.

Comment: Not sure what information is of interest for you in that webpage, i don't see any mention of a solution for you problem

Comment: `END() {
    let reason = this.$alexaSkill.getEndReason();

    // For example, log
    console.log(reason);

    this.tell('Goodbye!'); 
 },`

Comment: `this.tell('custom message')` I am not sure about that, cause that is a framework and I am not using any framework, but if it is possible by using framework then it should be possible without a framework.`

Comment: Please try to understand how this error is generated and read my answer for possible scenarios and solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to avoid it as much as possible.